BeautifulSoup in Python find() works as unexpected way with tuples
I am practicing crawling web, and yesterday I had an unexpected correct result which I dont think it should be work.
I used soup.find(id=i) to find the attribute key i, I though i must be string, but when I passed a tuple - which is first element of tuple is string that is key, and I was surprise when it still ran correct result.
let say '01' is the key of attribute, the code below had exact result with id='01'
tup = ('01', 'Revenue') acc = soup.find(id=tup).text.strip().split('\n')
Who has experience on this matter, please help me to explain? Thank you so much.
What I tried:
tup = ('01', 'Revenue')
acc = soup.find(id=tup).text.strip().split('\n')

I expect the KeyError because I passed a tuple instead of a string to id.

soup.find('id'=i) will raise a SyntaxError

@SIGHUP by looking at the longer code examples below this, one can assume this is just a typo. I edited the question.

I searched the BeautifulSoup source code
And found 3 occurrences where it checks if something is a tuple.
I haven't went to the whole chain of calls, but it seems to me that whenever you pass tuples or lists as arguments, BeautifulSoup will turn it into a space-separated string, and will further checks for every values.
I think this part is the actual unpacking / conversion:
From source code
    def _attr_value_as_string(self, value, default=None):
        """Force an attribute value into a string representation.

        A multi-valued attribute will be converted into a
        space-separated stirng.
        """
        value = self.get(value, default)
        if isinstance(value, list) or isinstance(value, tuple):
            value =" ".join(value)
        return value


It is more than clear, thank you for it.

Yes, you can pass tuple as a value ​​for attributes.
According to the official documentation, soup.find() does not only accept a string value for all the attributes, but also a list, a tuple, a regular expression, a function, or the value True.
While the official documentation primarily uses list to demonstrate multiple attribute values, tuple can also be used in the same way. Because, both list and tuple are iterable in Python. BeautifulSoup checks if the provided attribute value is iterable (like a list or tuple) and then iterates through the values to find a match.
So, if elements contain '01' or 'Revenue' as the id value in your soup. They will be matched without an error.
